# Mongoose: How to findById when the query is not complete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a search query where it will find a database object by its ID even while the user is typing.

```
ordersRouter.route('/searchorder/:term')
    .get(function(req, res){
        term = req.params.term;
        console.log(term);
        Orders.findById(term)
            .populate({ path: 'userPurchased products.product', select: '-username -password' })
            .exec(function(err, orders){
                if (err) throw err;

                res.json([orders]);
            });
    });
```

The problem here is that when the `term` does not exactly the same as the ID, it will return nothing. How can I return IDs with partial `term`?

**EDIT:** My order model schema

```
var orderSchema = new Schema({
    orderId: { type: String },
    userPurchased: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    products: [
        {
            product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products' },
            size: { type: String, required: true },
            quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
            subTotal: { type: Number, required: true }
        }
    ],
    totalQuantity: { type: Number },
    totalPrice: { type: Number },
    modeOfPayment: { type: String },
    shippingAd: { type: String },
    refNumber: { type: String },
    isDone: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    orderStatus: { type: String, default: 'Pending' },
    dateOrdered: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    fromNow: { type: String }
});
```

Comment: findById expects ID (type of ObjectID not a string nor integer nor anything else) as a parameter so why do you even try to give it something else?? I don't think you can actually do it like this. The best way i can think of is to give each order custom id of type String which you could then use to find by only part of the id.

Comment: so I can use find even if it is just partial text when I make my ID a string?

Comment: How can I do that? Just a normal find query?

Comment: i tried to make a custom id field with a type string. use the usual find method. not working.

Comment: sure. I edited my question. I also added orderId with the same value as my _id but with a type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your query using regex i.e. create a regular expression object from the string using the **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor then run the query as:

```
ordersRouter.route('/searchorder/:term')
    .get(function(req, res){
        term = req.params.term;
        console.log(term);

        Orders.find({'orderId': new RegExp(term)})
            .populate({ 
                path: 'userPurchased products.product', 
                select: '-username -password' 
            })
            .exec(function(err, orders){
                if (err) throw err;

                res.json(orders);
            });
    });
```

Comment: can this return an array of objects? I read that if I use regex it will only return one item.

Comment: Yes, `find().exe()` will return an array and no, regex will only return documents that match the given pattern, e.g. if you have in your `orders` collection the following documents `[ { orderId: 'test1' }, { orderId: 'test2' }, { orderId: 'test3' } ]`, the query `Orders.find({'orderId': new RegExp('test')})` will return all the docs as the regex `/test/` matches the three documents.

Comment: Can I also ask if search query is deleted and there is no value on `term` how can I display all the items again?